# How to Create A Dynamic Dns and MX-record via freedns.afraid.org

Tags: dynamic-dns

I'm in need of an mx record. I have comcast and they only allow you a few options for dynamic dns services, the free one being freedns.afraid.org. I've never set up an mx-record before so I obviously have little knowledge of what I'm dealing with. The options for both type "a" and "mx" are as follows:

```
Type:
Subdomain:  
Domain: crabdance.com   
Destination:
```

There is a dropdown selection of domains to choose from, I've chosen the crabdance.com domain.

For my 'A' record I have the following credentials.

```
Type: A
Subdomain:(myname)
Domain: crabdance.com
Destination: (public ip to my computer)
```

This results in (myname).crabdance.com

what would be a qualifying set of answers to fill out the mx record?

```
Type: A
Subdomain: [freedns.afraid.org says to leave this blank]
Domain: crabdance.com
Destination: ?
```

when I try to enter 10:mail.(myname).crabdance.com (this is recommended by freedns.afraid.org) I receive the following error messsage upon submitting the form:

```
Core subdomains (www, ftp, mail, irc, @) are reserved for the domain owner only [crabdance.com].
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set up for `MX rewcord` is as follows for `freedns.afraid.org`:

#### For A record:

```
Type: A
Subdomain:(myname)
Domain: crabdance.com
Destination: (public ip to my computer)
```

Now for the above **A record**, the **MX record** will look like:

```
Type: MX
Subdomain:(myname)
Domain: crabdance.com
Destination: 10:(myname).crabdance.com
```

Now any mail for say 'someone@(myname).crabdance.com`will be redirect to the server at`(myname).crabdance.com`

Do watch at `freedns.afraid.org` site, when you click on `Subdomain` on left side, two records as follows:

```
(myname).crabdance.com  A   public IP address
(myname).crabdance.com  MX  10:(myname).crabdance.com
```

If you using LINUX, one can install `inadyn` in order to update the dynamic IP address at regular intervals, like:

```
sudo apt-get install inadyn
```

Once done, open `inadyn.conf` file like:

```
sudo vim /etc/inadyn.conf
```

and place these lines:

```
system default@freedns.afraid.org
username yourusername
password yourpassword
update_period 60000
forced_update_period 320000
background
dyndns_system default@freedns.afraid.org
syslog
alias (myname).crabdance.com
```

Now you can run `inadyn` like:

```
sudo inadyn
```

to update the IP address. That is it :-)

Here is the screenshot of `freedns.afraid.org`

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Great answer! This worked for me. They really should have explained it better on their site.

Comment: @sudo: Thankyou and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this dynamic DNS service, but basically, they're telling you that the `mail` subdomain (probably even if you added a suffix like `mail.yourlogin`) is not permitted as they probably think you're trying to set a MX record for their own domain (`crabdance.com`).

In order to set the MX record, you should choose `Type: MX` where you have `Type: A` in your example. You indeed *should* fill in the subdomain with *myname* but without the *mail* keyword, and that should work.

In any case, if you still had problems, bear in mind that as per the [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5) documentation regarding to DNS records, if there's not a `MX record`, the `A` record will be used by default and will be used as it were the `MX` server.